# what methods could I use to step-up 700VDC to 5000VDC(approx)?

Tags: voltage, dc, converter

The input into my circuit is 5-15VDC; this passes through a digital potentiometer so that it can be controlled. Then there is a mini DC-DC converter which steps the voltage up to 700VDC. Now I need a way to get from that 700VDC to around 5000VDC.

I'm using a DC-DC converter as well because I thought with a voltage of 700 it might be easier to boost that compared to a lower voltage.

Also, if you know of a way to boost the voltage from the input value up to around 5000VDC, without using a converter to raise it to 700VDC first, then please suggest it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look for "flyback transformer" and associated circuits, as used in CRT televisions. Obviously safety becomes extremely important. What is the 5kV for?

Comment: @pjc50 I thought transformers wouldn't work DC-DC? Also the I need 5kV because I need to create a powerful electric field that is necessary for my project.

Comment: What current would this signal be at? Are we talking nano/microamperes, or higher?

Comment: Transformers do indeed require AC, but you can rectify it on the far side. The other option is a cascade multiplier.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh  I can't remember the amp value at the moment because all my notes are not with me at the moment. I remember it being low but that doesn't help. I could get the value later though...

Comment: @pjc50 I've been looking at voltage multipliers, etc but most of the require an AC input and I don't really want to use a clunky DC-AC inverter, also using AC as an input isn't really practical for me.

Comment: @pjc50 However the Cockcroft–Walton generator can produce a high DC voltage from a low AC voltage input OR a pulsing DC input. Now Im not that knowledgable so how would I produce a pulsing DC input?

Comment: You can buy pakaged EHT generators. While this is "easy enough to do" it's also easy to kill primary side electronics if things go wrong. If you can afford a commercial solution it may be worthwhile. The small cheap Black and White TVs which were common years ago and which can still be bought will have an EHT generator circuit. Voltage probably too low. It may prove too hard to dis-integrate.

Comment: The best method all depends on your budget, expected discharge or current. This determines the output capacitor rating. The stetup voltage is easy but you still need to specify the load current. The amount of noise radiated is another consideration. There too many options.chop and step-up XFMR, switch boost pulse (SMPS regulator) etc.. and inductorless clock switched diode cap multipliers. Flash converters can generate this from batteries.

Answer (score 1):

A switching regulator is the best way to go about this. You take your 500VDC input, chop it at high frequency, apply the chopped signal to a magnetic component (inductor or transformer) to create your higher voltage, then re-rectify it to get DC out.

If you don't care about isolation between input and output, you can use a [boost converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter).

If you need isolation, as Olin said you can use a [flyback converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter), which uses a transformer to achieve galvanic isolation between input and output.

It's difficult to get from 5-15V to 5kV with a single-stage converter (the duty cycle would be a challenge) so your intermediate stage of 700V isn't actually a bad idea. You lose a bit on efficiency with cascaded converters, but at least the conversion is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind.  The first is a flyback step-up converter.  A good example of this in everyday use is a car ignition coil.  The primary is energized with 12 V, and the secondary puts out enough for a spark to jump a few mm gap.  In fact, a car ignition coil is a commonly available flyback transformer that might be just what you want if this is a one-off.  A flyback booster inherently produces pulses, not DC, but this is easily rectified and then dumped onto a capacitor.

The second approach is a Cockroft-Walton ladder.  This again uses AC, with each stage adding the input AC to the accumulating total, minus the diode drops.  Basically this is a ladder of diodes and capacitors.  I won't go into the topology since there is much written about this out there.  This again inherenetly works on AC, but the output always has a capacitor accross it already.  These things are generally better when you have a reasonably high input voltage since each stage just adds another level of the input voltage.  In other words, the output is the input voltage times the number of stages (minus diode drops).  You need a lot of stages if the output to input voltage is a large ratio.  The current capability is also rather limited since it is basically a bunch of capacitive charge pumps in series.

You didn't say what current you need or give other particulars, so there is little more useful to say here.

Comment: The current I need can be anything within reason because the circuit's use is only to produce a strong electric field.

Comment: There is an easy way to get a high DC voltage from a low DC voltage... using a proportional DC conveter from EMCO HV however I would need around 14 of these which cost $184 per piece!